# Insert copied Cells into Excel with Python Win32Com

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

The following code will copy the intended range then insert in the intended spot shifting the cells right.

```
ws.Range("H3:M7).Copy()
ws.Range("H3").Insert()
```

However I want it to shift the cells down not right. But the following code gives me an Insert method of Range class failed error.

```
ws.Range("H3:M7).Copy()
ws.Range("H3").Insert(Shift="xlShiftDown")
```

any suggestions? ws is obtained from Workbooks.Sheets("My Sheet") within the win32com excel application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use

```
ws.Range("H3").Insert(Shift=win32com.client.constants.xlShiftDown)
```

[reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa170491(v=office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

excel.Visible = True

file = r'Drive:\\path\\wincom_test.xlsx'
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)

wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate()
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H3:M7").Select()
excel.Selection.Cut(Destination=wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H4:M8"))
```